# Unable to import C2DMBaseReceiver - Android 2.2Version: 8.0.1.v201012062107-82219 on Eclipse 3.6.0

Tags: android

I am trying to use the C2DMI Push notification but have compilation problems.  Can anyone please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this receiver: http://code.google.com/p/chrometophone/source/browse/trunk/android/c2dm/com/google/android/c2dm/C2DMBaseReceiver.java?r=2